# Same height for div's

Tags: html, css

I want that 3 div's are having the same height.

**Picture**
 [image: Not teh same Hight]

**HTML**

```css
 .more-bottom {
    padding: 4em 0;
    background: #DCEDF9;
    }
    .more-bottom-grids {
    margin: 4em 0 4em 0;
    height: 10px;
    }
    .more-bottom-grid-img img {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .more-bottom-grid-info {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: .5em;
    }
    .more-bottom-grid-text {
    padding: 1em;
    }
    .more-bottom-grid-text h5 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .875em;
    color: #383838;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    .more-bottom-grid-text p {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    font-size: .875em;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="more-bottom-grids">
    <div class="col-md-4 more-bottom-grid">
     <div class="more-bottom-grid-info">
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-img" id="experienceutrecht">
       <img src="images/ExperienceUtrecht/Attractions/Architecture/8.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-text">
       <h5>Stadhuis</h5>
       <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Korte Minrebroederstraat 2, 3512 GG Utrecht</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 more-bottom-grid">
     <div class="more-bottom-grid-info">
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-img" id="experienceutrecht">
       <img src="images/ExperienceUtrecht/Attractions/Architecture/9.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-text">
       <h5>Stadskantoor</h5>
       <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stadsplateau 1, 3521 AZ Utrecht</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 more-bottom-grid">
     <div class="more-bottom-grid-info">
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-img" id="experienceutrecht">
       <img src="images/ExperienceUtrecht/Attractions/Architecture/10.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="more-bottom-grid-text">
       <h5>The Wall</h5>
       <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hertogswetering 183, 3543 AS Utrecht</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

How do I get the same height for these 3 blocks?
This is on my website, so if you want to you can see it live [here](http://jhollander.eu/architecture).

I have tried to change some things by the img with specific height, but it didn't worked yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should user min-height css property for same div something like that

```
.more-bottom-grid-info {
background: #FFF;
padding: 0.5em;
min-height: 340px;
```

}

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You really only have two options.

1. Set a min height on each card (the container with white background).
2. Use flexbox, I'd recommend checking out the card group section over at [flexboxpatterns](http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/card-group) for a detailed walktrough.

Comment: Thanks! I use the min-height now.